# Memory Leaks - STL sets

Tags: c++, stl, set, memory-leaks

I am trying to plug up all my memory leaks (which is massive). I am new to STL. I have a class library where I have 3 sets. I am also creating a lot of memory with new in the library class for adding info to the sets...

Do I need to deallocate the sets? If so, how?

Here is the library.h

```
    #pragma once

#include <ostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;

typedef set<Item*>              ItemSet;
typedef map<string,Item*>       ItemMap;
typedef map<string,ItemSet*>    ItemSetMap;

class Library
{

public:
    // general functions

    void addKeywordForItem(const Item* const item, const string& keyword);
    const ItemSet* itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword) const;
    void printItem(ostream& out, const Item* const item) const;

    // book-related functions

    const Item* addBook(const string& title, const string& author, int const nPages);
    const ItemSet* booksByAuthor(const string& author) const;
    const ItemSet* books() const;

    // music-related functions

    const Item* addMusicCD(const string& title, const string& band, const int nSongs);
    void addBandMember(const Item* const musicCD, const string& member);
    const ItemSet* musicByBand(const string& band) const;
    const ItemSet* musicByMusician(const string& musician) const;
    const ItemSet* musicCDs() const;

    // movie-related functions

    const Item* addMovieDVD(const string& title, const string& director, const int nScenes);
    void addCastMember(const Item* const movie, const string& member);
    const ItemSet* moviesByDirector(const string& director) const;
    const ItemSet* moviesByActor(const string& actor) const;
    const ItemSet* movies() const;
    ~Library();
};
```

I am not sure what i need to do for the destructor?

```
Library::~Library()
{


}
```

also, am I de allocating the stringset right?

```
    #ifndef CD_H
#define CD_H
#pragma once
#include "item.h"
#include <set>


typedef set<string> StringSet;


class CD : public Item
{
public:

    CD(const string& theTitle, const string& theBand, const int snumber);
    void addBandMember(const string& member);
    const int getNumber() const;
    const StringSet* getMusician() const;
    const string getBand() const;
    virtual void print(ostream& out) const;
    string printmusicians(const StringSet* musicians) const;

    ~CD();


private:

    string band;
    StringSet* music;

    string title;
    int number;

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CD* cd);

#endif
```

cd.cpp

```
    #include "CD.h"

using namespace std;

CD::CD(const string& theTitle, const string& theBand, const int snumber)
: Item(theTitle), band(theBand),number(snumber), music(new StringSet)
{



}

CD::~CD()
{

    delete []music;

}
```

in the library class I am creating a lot of memory, but dont the destructor clean that up?
example:

```
    const Item* Library::addBook(const string& title, const string& author, const int nPages)
{

    ItemSet* obj = new ItemSet();
    Book* item = new Book(title,author,nPages);
    allBooks.insert(item); // add to set of all books
    obj->insert(item);
```

Note: I do not have a copy constructor. I am not sure if I even need one or how top add one. I dont think my destructors are getting called either..

Comment: Short answer: Search for every instance of the `*` character in your code, and delete it. You hardly ever need to use pointers in C++. Every time you do, you're asking for memory leaks.

Comment: There are plenty of times you need to use pointers in C++, even if you use standard types.

Comment: In this case, `Item` is a base class for the stored objects, so you have to store pointers in `ItemSet` and `ItemMap`. Storing smart pointers will fix those leaks. `ItemSetMap` should just contain set objects.

Comment: Yes there are exceptions, but have you even looked at the OP's code? He's using pointers for *everytihng*. Containers store pointers, every object is referenced through pointers, everything is dynamically allocated, everything must be cleaned up. Are you seriously telling me that it is "paranoia" to tell him he shouldn't use pointers for all these things?

Comment: @Steve314: these aren't "possible" problems, these are real problems. You can't sensibly add cleanup code to standard containers' destructors and, even if you do, there will still be leaks when you remove or overwrite items in the container. Fixing memory leaks is neither paranoid nor sacred; it's part of making software that works.

Comment: My past comments deleted not as incorrect, but as excessive and inappropriate here.

Comment: Actually I don't see how you can meaningfully have a `set<Item*>` in the first place. You can't overload `operator<` for two pointer types, hence the set would be ordered by addresses, and hence you won't be able to look up anything in the set (without iterating it linearly) unless you already have that pointer stored elsewhere. (Which would mean that you already have the object that you wanted to look up.)

Comment: My understanding is that using smart pointers in container classes can be dangerous. If the container needs to relocate the objects, problems can occur. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577838/smart-pointers-in-container-like-stdvector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to free the memory for each element of the set. The container will not do that for you, and it shouldn't because it can't know whether it owns that data or not -- it could just be holding pointers to objects owned by something else.

This is a generic free function that will deallocate any STL container.

```
template <typename T>
void deallocate_container(T& c)
{
  for (typename T::iterator i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i)
    delete *i;
}

// Usage
set<SomeType*> my_set;
deallocate_container(my_set);
my_set.clear();
```

Comment: But you need RTTI for that, hah!

Comment: Why would you need RTTI for this?

Comment: It probably needs the classes to have virtual destructors. Most classes need virtual destructors anyway. The problem is a property of the class, not this deallocate_container function, IOW. One issue though - does it work for std::map, which has key and data for each item, either or both potentially a pointer?

Comment: Yeah, it requires a virtual destructor, but that's orthogonal to the use of this function. And yeah, it won't work with maps because the iterators point to pairs. For maps, you could have dynamically allocated memory in the key and/or value, so you'd need to write versions for those specially.

Answer (score 4):

STL containers are not designed to hold pointers.

Look at the boost pointer containers. These containers are designed to hold pointers.

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_set.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_set.html

The containers hold and own the pointers so they will be deleted when the container goes out of scope. But the beautiful thing about the containers is that you access the objects via references so all the standard algorithms work without any special adapters.

```
typedef boost::ptr_set<Item>              ItemSet;
typedef boost::ptr_map<string,Item>       ItemMap;
typedef boost::ptr_map<string,ItemSet>    ItemSetMap;
```

PS. Its hard to tell accurately but it looks like too many of your interfaces return pointers. It is very rare in C++ to actually return pointers (or pass pointers around). Your interfaces should usually take objects/references or smart pointers (usually in that order but it depends on the situation).

Working with a pointer should be your last resort as there is no clear indication of the owner of the object and thus cleanup becomes the issue (thus leading to massive memory leaks).

Answer (score 1):

haven't gone through all of your code but from the first few lines it seems you're maintaining sets of pointers. Whenever you have an STL container which holds pointers and you're using `new` to put stuff in the pointers, you must use delete to deallocate these pointers. STL doesn't do that for you. In fact, STL doesn't even know they are pointers.

Another option is to not use pointers at all and have a set of just the objects and not use `new` to create them. Just create them on the stack and copy them into the set.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be a stupid comment, but do you really need to have ALL your stuff heap-allocated (aka. using pointers and new ?)

Can't you just use plain instances ? RAII allows easier code and no memory leak.

For example have :

```
using namespace std;

typedef set<Item>              ItemSet;
typedef map<string,Item>       ItemMap;
typedef map<string,ItemSet>    ItemSetMap;

class Library
{

public:
    // general functions

    void addKeywordForItem(const Item & item, const string& keyword);
    ItemSet itemsForKeyword(const string& keyword) const;
    void printItem(ostream& out, const Item & item) const;

    // book-related functions

    Item addBook(const string& title, const string& author, int nPages);
    ItemSet booksByAuthor(const string& author) const;
    ItemSet books() const;

    // music-related functions

    Item addMusicCD(const string& title, const string& band, int nSongs);
    void addBandMember(const Item & musicCD, const string& member);
    ItemSet musicByBand(const string& band) const;
    ItemSet musicByMusician(const string& musician) const;
    ItemSet musicCDs() const;

    // movie-related functions

    Item addMovieDVD(const string& title, const string& director, int nScenes);
    void addCastMember(const Item & movie, const string& member);
    ItemSet moviesByDirector(const string& director) const;
    ItemSet moviesByActor(const string& actor) const;
    ItemSet movies() const;
    ~Library();
};
```

With this approach, the destructor has to do strictly nothing, and no memory leak. In most cases using pointers can be easily avoided, and definetly should!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some of the code you posted in other questions (such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376099/c-add-to-stl-set), your items are stored in several global `ItemSet` objects. This isn't a good design - they really should be part of the `Library` object, since they logically belong to that.

The best way to fix the memory leaks is not to deal with raw pointers - either store smart pointers in the sets, or use Boost pointer containers as Martin York suggests. Also, your `ItemSetMap` objects should contain `Set` objects rather than pointers - there is absolutely no reason to store pointers in them.

If you really must store pointers, then your destructor must walk through each set to delete the contents:

```
void Purge(ItemSet &set)
{
    for (ItemSet::iterator it = set.begin(); it != set.end(); ++it)
        delete *it;
    set.clear(); // since we won't actually be destroying the container
}

void Purge(ItemSetMap &map)
{
    for (ItemSetMap::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
        delete it->second;
    map.clear();
}

Library::~Library()
{
    Purge(allBooks);
    Purge(allCDs);
    // and so on and so forth
}
```

but this really isn't how you should be doing it, as just about everyone answering your questions has pointed out.

As for the `StringSet`, you created it with plain `new` not `new[]`, so you must delete it with plain `delete` not `delete[]`. Or, better still, make `music` a `StringSet` object rather than a pointer, then you won't need the destructor at all. Once again, memory management through raw pointers and manual use of `delete` is error prone, and should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: I also have typedef set<string> StringSet;
StringSet* Moviecast; can i just use delete Moviecast on it? or do i have to iterate?

Comment: No, you don't have to iterate a `set<string>`, since that contains objects and will deallocate them itself. You only need to delete objects that you allocated using `new`, and you should avoid doing that whenever you can.

Comment: i used new to add info to my sets in almost all my functions like: ItemSet* obj = new ItemSet();  how do i delete those? i cannot delete those before it leaves the function. - i hope oyu dont mind but i used your purge functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the destructor you need to iterate over your stl collections that contain pointers and delete them. Like this:

```
while (!collection.empty()) {
    collection_type::iterator it = collection.begin();
    your_class* p = *it;
    collection.erase(it);
    delete p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you need to deallocate the pointers. The `set` destructor normally wouldn't do this for you. Otherwise, if you want this to be done for you, use a `boost::scoped_ptr` or a `std::tr1::shared_ptr` where you can specify a custom deleter to do this job for you.