# memory management for vector of pointers

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass : private vector<AnotherClass*> {
//some codes
}
```

How do I implement its destructor? I am new to C++ and have totally no clue on this.

Thanks in advance!

edit: fixed the syntax,thx for remaindering me!

Comment: Wait. You want to derive `vector`?

Comment: First, you don't inherit from standard containers. If you need your object to use one, use composition.

Comment: I recommend you read this thread: [Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector)

Answer (score 3):

Don't derive from std::vector. Better use std::vector and a smart pointer class like shared_ptr or unique_ptr (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577838/smart-pointers-in-container-like-stdvector)).

And a warning: don't use std::auto_ptr in containers because it will not work as expected in most circumstances.