# C++ smart vector with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

Learning smart pointers and stumble upon this problem: How would I create a vector with objects that auto deletes themselves? Below is a snippet of how I have it at the moment, is this the correct way to ensure I don't need to call delete on anything?

```
unique_ptr<vector<unique_ptr<OBJ>>> list(new vector<unique_ptr<OBJ>>);
```

Comment: You can't use `auto_ptr`, but `unique_ptr` is fine if your compiler provides it. You need move semantics to get the correct behavior.

Comment: @CodeGray No complains from the compiler so I take it it's working then, why wouldn't auto_ptr work?

Comment: `auto_ptr` has rather unusual semantics, such that copying it actually transfers ownership rather than making a copy. Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577838/smart-pointers-in-container-like-stdvector, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876641/so-can-unique-ptr-be-used-safely-in-stl-collections

Comment: That first unique_ptr is probably redundant. vector<unique_ptr<OBJ>> list; is probably enough. This is not Java where you have to 'new' absolutely everything...

Comment: If you put objects to a vector then they will be destroyed when the vector is, not clear why use smart pointer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H.Guijt pointed out the redundancy on calling new on the vector itself, following code should be sufficient:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Entry>> list;
```